# How to use custom CSS on a default Sphinx theme?

Tags: python, css, python-sphinx

I'm creating documentation in Python with the Sphinx default theme `agogo`.

I would like to use the `topic` directive to put a box around important information but agogo's CSS doesn't have a border in it's default CSS. I have the CSS to create the border created, but how to I include/override the old version of agogo's `topic` to use my version instead.

I want to be able to generate the docs without changing the CSS manually every time. I researched a bit about using custom CSS with Sphinx but nothing seems to mention overriding an existing class.

Comment: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/adding-custom-css.html#overriding-or-replacing-a-theme-s-stylesheet

Comment: The following link explains how it works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity . Basically you have to either specify the selector deeper the the that from the orginal style sheet, give the element that you want to change an ID and call that one in css, or add `!important` to the element you really want. `!important` is bad practice since it can make other parts of  your site not work like expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here we (ago)go:

1. Create a file called custom.css in the `_static` subdirectory of the Sphinx project.
2. In custom.css, add `@import 'agogo.css';` and your own custom CSS code.
3. Add `html_style = 'custom.css'` to conf.py ([documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_style)).

Comment: thanks, that worked. I copied the 'code' element from classic.css, and replced ``font-size: 0.95em`` with "font-size: 1.1em"