# rinohtype export to PDF - document header with chapter name and title

Tags: python-sphinx, rinohtype

I'd like to define and style header as shown on the picture - the light part contains chapter name, document title is in the dark one.

Now I can only have the light grey section with text aligned to the right.

How can I define header style to achieve this? Also how can I insert those squares into the layout?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You can [customize themes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython-sphinx%5D+customize+theme) however you like with your own CSS and modifying the theme templates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use custom CSS on a default sphinx theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57415129/how-to-use-custom-css-on-a-default-sphinx-theme)

Comment: @StevePiercy I think this question is about PDF output using rinohtype.

Answer (score 3):

**I'd like to define and style header as shown on the picture - the light part contains chapter name, document title is in the dark one.**

Unfortunately, this functionality is not yet documented well. Here are the steps necessary to obtain this:

1. Set a custom template configuration in `conf.py` if you haven't done so yet

   ```python
   rinoh_documents = [dict(doc='index', target='manual', template='my_template.rtt')]
   ```
2. Define the [page header content](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/api/template.html#rinoh.template.PageTemplate.header_text) in the template configuration (`my_template.rtt`)

   ```ini
   [TEMPLATE_CONFIGURATION]
   name = My Template
   template = article
   stylesheet = my_stylesheet.rts

   [contents_page]
   header_text = '\t' '{SECTION_TITLE(1)}' (header section title)
                 '\t' '{DOCUMENT_TITLE}' (header document title)
   ```
3. [Style the header text](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/style/rinoh.text.TextStyle.html#rinoh.text.TextStyle) and adjust the [tab stop positions and alignment](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/style/rinoh.paragraph.ParagraphStyle.html#rinoh.paragraph.ParagraphStyle.tab_stops) in the style sheet (`my_stylesheet.rts`)

   ```ini
   [STYLESHEET]
   name = My Style Sheet
   base = sphinx_article

   [header]
   tab_stops=12cm RIGHT, 100% RIGHT

   [header section title : StyledText('header section title')]
   base = default
   font_weight = bold

   [header document title : StyledText('header document title')]
   base = header section title
   font_slant = italic
   ```

**Also how can I insert those squares (in front of the text) into the layout?**

For black squares, you can insert a unicode character, for example the aptly named [BLACK SQUARE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25a0/index.htm) character using [python-style escape sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#the-string-type) or simply pasting the character into the template configuration:

```ini
[contents_page]
header_text = '\t' '\N{BLACK SQUARE} {SECTION_TITLE(1)}' (header section title)
              '\t' '■' (header square) ' {DOCUMENT_TITLE}' (header document title)
```

As you can see, you an style the square differently (e.g. larger font).

You can also use inline images, if unicode (or the font) doesn't cover your needs:

```ini
[contents_page]
header_text = '\t' IMAGE('img/square.png', scale=0.3) ' {SECTION_TITLE(1)}' (header section title)
              '\t' IMAGE('img/circle.png', scale=0.3) '{DOCUMENT_TITLE}' (header document title)
```

<strike>**Also how can I insert those squares into the layout?**</strike> **Adding a background for the page headers**

You can set a [background image](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/api/template.html#rinoh.template.PageTemplate.background) on the page template in your template configuration. You can draw this in a vector drawing application such as [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) and export it to PDF.

```ini
[contents_page]
background='img/contents_background.pdf' scale=fill
```

You can adjust the placement of the header text by adjusting the [margins](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/api/template.html#rinoh.template.PageTemplate.left_margin) and [header_footer_distance](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/api/template.html#rinoh.template.PageTemplate.header_footer_distance) in the page template configuration and .

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try. Regarding the squares - they're more like bullets in list, not some special background elements.

Comment: @KarelFrajták Ah, I misunderstood your question. Answer updated!